# How to store parent comment id in comment-replay system (how to pass a value from view to controller?)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a website using codeIgniter in which I have created a comment field with replay button to each comment.

I am displaying comments using foreach loop and know database structure for this system but how do i store the comment id  on replaying to that particular comment..?

my code is something like this:

```
 <?php 
    foreach ( $data as $value){
    $id = $value['comment_id']; // comment id
    echo $value['comment'].'<br>';
    ?>
    <textarea><input type="submit" value="replay"> //for repaly
    <?php } ?>
```

To be clear how do I pass comment id from view to controller..?

since it is in foreach loop does it indicate to corresponding comment..?

any suggestion would be welcomed. 
thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the comment id as a hidden field in the form you are submitting, then it will be in the form data in the controller.

```
<form action="YOUR_URL" method="POST">

<YOUR_FORM_ELEMENTS_HERE>
<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="<YOUR_COMMENT_ID>">
<input type="submit" value="replay">

</form>
```